# Load a video as byte in Visual Studio from Properties

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have created a C# Console Application project and I want to load a video but I am not being able to, this is what is happening:

[image]

I have manually added Resources from the Project settings, since before, I couldn't use the `Propierties` class. Now I'm able to, but I can't load the video.

Notice that I am using the correct namespace name.

I have also created the folder Resources and tried this:

`byte[] archivo = ConsoleApplication7.Resources.videoplayback.mp4;`

But nothing, not sure how to load it.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `Resources.resx` file, which compiles to a type usable from code, and a `Resources` folder, which has no relation whatsoever to the former.

Add the video file to your resources file, if that's what you want.

Or use a `FileStream` and simply read the file from disk as opposed to from a resource.

Comment: FileStream would have been an option, but what I had to do was to add an Existing Item to the Resource with Visual Studio, thank you anyway